# How to upgrade iDRAC firmware and BIOS of Dell PowerEdge R510?

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell, drac

I have a Dell PowerEdge R510 with iDRAC Enterprise:

- System Model: PowerEdge R510
- System Revision:  II
- Service Tag:  70BMGS1
- Express Service Code: 15257000305
- BIOS Version: 1.8.2
- Firmware Version: 1.80 (Build 17)
- Lifecycle Controller Firmware:    1.5.1.57

I want to upgrade the BIOS and the iDRAC firmware. I fed it each of these files from Dell's R510 downloads page (iDRAC Settings -> Firmware Update on the web UI), but each time, it came back with "File is not valid for iDRAC Firmware update":

- ESM_Firmware_MXKG2_LN32_2.91_A00.BIN
- ESM_Firmware_NVJ9K_LN32_1.90_A00.BIN
- iDRAC6_1.85_A00_FW_IMG.exe
- R510_BIOS_PYCXX_WN64_1.14.0.EXE
- R510_ESM_Firmware_F8T9F_WN32_1.92_A00.EXE

Based on Dell forums, I should do a staged update, but 1.85 is the oldest version of what I think is the iDRAC firmware available on Dell's site.

For newer servers like R620 and R630, I was able to just feed the iDRAC any firmware file from Dell's website (BIOS or iDRAC or otherwise) and it figured out what to do with it. Any idea how I should perform the upgrade?

Comment: The reason I haven't tried the OMSA live DVD yet is because the reason I'm updating the iDRAC in the first place is because the virtual console is unreliable; arrow keys don't work, the mouse is nearly impossible to use, and the virtual media disconnects randomly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As shown in the training video in section 4 of the support article [Dell PowerEdge: How to a Remote Firmware Update with the iDRAC?](https://www.dell.com/support/article/nz/en/nzdhs1/sln292363/dell-poweredge-how-to-a-remote-firmware-update-with-the-idrac-?lang=en), you must manually unzip `iDRAC6_1.85_A00_FW_IMG.exe` and upload the actual image file `firmimg.d6` to the iDRAC.  The more recent iDRAC models can accept the executable file directly and unzip it themselves, but apparently the iDRAC 6 can't.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing @Harry Johnston
I have poweredge T420 idrac 7 and it wouldn't take the .bin file.  Had to extract and get the .d7 files inside payload/ folder.

Alternatively, I discovered the ESM tools from dell [Dell EMC System Update](http://Dell%20EMC%20System%20Update)

Specifically:
Installation method using Linux repository
Setup the repository

```
curl -s https://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/dsu/bootstrap.cgi | bash
```

Installing DSU
RedHat Enterprise Linux Servers
`yum install dell-system-update`

SUSE Enterprise Linux Servers
`zypper install dell-system-update`

Note: If signature keys are not available, please run below command to update the signature keys

```
curl -s https://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/dsu/bootstrap.cgi | bash
```

The install instructions can be found [here](https://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/DSU_19.05.00/)

Once installed you can run `dsu -u` and it will check all your hardware including BIOS and prompt for all the necessary updates you can choose from.